# mongodb:when show tables ,show errors uncaught exception: error: { "$err" : "assertion db/pdfile.h:259" }

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i want to show tables in a database,but it show errors,as

```
dxt:PRIMARY> show tables
Tue Jul  3 14:58:46 uncaught exception: error: { "$err" : "assertion db/pdfile.h:259" }
```

what is is the problem?

thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a sudden shutdown or face a crash? Can you check the folder you specified in dbpath if the .ns file is missing.. This file contains all this metadata required for querying..

Comment: thank you for your help. yes,the server crash。i can't find the dbname.ns file,it was lost...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your database was corrupted somehow.  Similar to the problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/jA-RhdMfM7Y).  You can try running a repair but do note that it will remove corrupted data:

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

Comment: thank you for your help. but it still error.as  dxt:PRIMARY> db.repairDatabase()
{
 "errmsg" : "exception: nextSafe(): { $err: \"assertion db/pdfile.h:259\" }",
 "code" : 13106,
 "ok" : 0
}